# Twig path() function generating different paramter

Tags: php, symfony, path, twig

I want different parameter names for different routes. So instead of using a fix name for the paramter like here

```
<a href="{{ path('page_edit', { 'param': item.value }) }}">Submit</a>
```

I want to do somethinig like this

```
<a href="{{ path('page_edit', { '{{ item.param }}': item.value }) }}">Submit</a>
```

But what I get as result looks like this

```
http://localhost/mysite/web/app_dev.php/user/edit?%7B%7B+item.param+%7D%7D=1918
```

How can I generate a result that looks like this?

```
http://localhost/mysite/web/app_dev.php/user/edit/1918
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky one, from the doc:

`{# keys as expressions (the expression must be enclosed into parentheses) #}
{% set foo = 'foo' %}
{ (foo): 'foo', (1 + 1): 'bar', (foo ~ 'b'): 'baz' }`

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html

So in your case:

`<a href="{{ path('page_edit', { (item.param): item.value }) }}">Submit</a>`